# Custom View automatically erased?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I created a View in my database, was performing queries just fine and went back to update it to add a column.

There was a syntax error of some kind, I misspelled column name or something and then the entire view was erased from my database. I can't find any way to get it back, and this is hours of work just gone.

Is this a common behavior in MySql Workbench? How do I keep the software from erasing things in the future? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do your work in an editor or IDE, not Workbench.

Comment: is MySql Workbench not an editor? I use it to write and edit queries and so do all my coworkers.

Comment: this also doesn't really answer my question about why MySql Workbench just erased my view without me telling it to.  I've been editing and creating views here for a while now and this has never happened to me before. I can't even manage to recreate the deletion with other views in our database. I need to know what I did wrong to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: In order to create a view, it first has to drop the old view, otherwise it will get an error because the name is already in use.

Comment: I've never used Workbench, so I don't know its specifics.

Comment: even if there was a syntax error, the view's code should still be in the editor in workbench. You really should describe what you have done, step-by-step, otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: The code is no longer there, MySql Workbench closed that tab.
After I edited the view, clicked "Apply".

The apply dialog appeared, I click "Apply" again. There is some sort of syntax error, I click cancel or the x button. My view is gone forever.

Comment: The view should still be in your database. Try `show create view <name>` (of course use the name of your view). Or use the schema navigator under Views and click refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to recreate the entire view.

Be careful when editing a view because I guess sometimes MySQL Workbench will drop the view, have an error when creating the new (edited) view, and then fail to restore the old one.

You'd think MySQL would use a transaction to do this but apparently not. Stay safe out there.